# Google Material line chart getChartLayoutInterface() is missing, how to add images to dataline?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have google material Line chart and need to get X and Y position of some datapoint in layout for add image to graph area... But web page in browser says:

```
chart.getChartLayoutInterface is not a function
```

I found, there is no method getChartLayoutInterface() in Google Material graphs available. If I switch this code to "classic graph" code (comment/uncomment) in code, that my example works...

There is my code:

```
var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
var chart = new google.charts.Line(container);

    //If I Uncomment this line, google uses old "Classic" line graphs and that works...
    //var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {

    var layout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();

        var xPos = layout.getXLocation(data.getValue(210, 0));
        var yPos = layout.getYLocation(data.getValue(210, 2));

        var GameEvent = container.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));

        GameEvent.src = '/nuke.png';
        GameEvent.style.top = (yPos -0) + 'px';
        GameEvent.style.left = (xPos) + 'px';
      }

    );
```

But I need to use material graphs (it works better on google chromecast as renderer).

Can you have any solution for me?

Comment: the method simply isn't supported by material charts. you can use classic chart with following option --> `theme: 'material'`

Comment: you can also use the native SVG method `getBBox` on any of the chart's SVG elements, if you can find the chart element you want to reference. if you add points to your line, then you could find the `<circle>` element. the `<circle>` elements would be in the same order as the rows in the data table.